# MySQL UPDATE statement does not update the entry in the database

Tags: php, mysql

There are not error that the mysql code is throwing in anyway. I tried to test the mysql statement in the Workbench and it works, it updates the entry.
Here is my php code that adds the entry to the database. The second query works while the first one does not get entered in the database

```
 //Editing the Item


$updateEntry1 ="UPDATE item 
                SET price=120
                WHERE itemName ='Cebu - Manila Airplane Ticket';";

retrieveTable($updateEntry1);


//Retrieve item id through searching the item name in the 'item' table

$selectId = "SELECT id
             FROM   item
             WHERE  itemName = '".$_POST['itemTravel']."';";
$retrieveId = retrieveTable($selectId);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($retrieveId);
```

Here is the retrieve table function which is a function that stores the info in the db

```
function retrieveTable($query){
$config = parse_ini_file('/config.ini'); 
$connect = mysqli_connect($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)or die (mysqli_error($connect)); 
return $filter_Result;}
```

s

Comment: Have you checked that your config file is being loaded

Comment: yes it is actually working since I've been using the function in other parts of the code and it works

Answer (score 0):

You have two SQL statements in your query text. Run `mysqli_query()` separately for each statement.

You're probably running only the first statement the way you have your code now.